# Qualitative theory of ODE's

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $~f~$ be a $C^{1}$ function defined over the reals, and let $~x(t)~$ be a solution to the differential equation:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$$
Suppose that $~\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x(t)=c~$, then prove that $~f(c)=0~$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $|f(c)|=\alpha>0$. Then by continuity There exists interval $I\ni c$ s.t. $f\geq\alpha/2>0$ on $I$ without loosing generality. For $t_\alpha>0$ large enough so that for all $t\geq t_\alpha$, $x(t)\in I$, (this is because $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}x(t)=c$) $x'(t)=f(x(t))\geq\alpha/2>0$. Therefore, $$x(t)-x(t_\alpha)=\int_{t_\alpha}^tx'(\tilde{t})d\tilde{t}\geq\int_{t_\alpha}^t\frac{\alpha}{2}d\tilde{t}\xrightarrow{t\rightarrow \infty}+\infty,$$ clearly a contradiction.